# how can I reset a canon pixma iP4950?

Tags: canon

When my canon is powered up, the power led and the stop led flash interchangeably for 10 times (there is no paper jam, the print head is clean and the inks are new). I need a way to reset it, so that I can print.

Comment: Please check your user's manual. That's a code with some meaning.

Comment: There is no reference about such error codes in the manual - otherwise I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: Do you have an error message when it is connected to a computer?

Comment: Pixma flash codes, https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/ErrorCode/MG3600%20series/EN/ERR/err_ug_message01_0100.html. Alternate flashes to a total of 10 means incompatible paper form duplex. Try setting it to print one-sided?

Comment: @ SébastienC: I have a Linux box - the behaviour is different here. According to my research it looks like a B200 :(

Comment: @ pbhj: Thanks for the link, but the model is different (mine is an iP4950).